# Why doesn't thins BST code work (C)

Tags: c, pointers

```
void add_bst(struct node **tloc, int k, int v)
{
    struct node *nd;
    nd = search_bst(*tloc, k);
    nd = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nd->key=k;
    nd->value=v;
    nd->left=NULL;
    nd->right=NULL;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that search_bst is correctly written, but this function seems to be a no-op. What am I doing wrong? Sorry if it's something super obvious, but I'm a C newbie.

Edit: here's search_bst:

```
struct node *search_bst(struct node *t, int k)
{
    while (t != NULL){
            if (t->key < k) t = t->right;
            else if (t->key > k) t = t->left;
            else return t;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: How can we know what search_bst does when you haven't provided it?

Comment: How do we know what `add_bst()` is supposed to do to figure out where it's doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a result from search_bst here:

```
nd = search_bst(*tloc, k);
```

Then here you are assigning to nd again, which means that it no longer points to the previous result:

```
nd = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

So you're throwing away the result from search_bst.

Comment: How should I fix it then?

Comment: I'm trying to modify the node search_bst returns...

Comment: Now that I see search_bst, you have a design problem.  You intend to add a node to your tree.  But search_bst will only return a node if one already exists, and is going to return NULL if the node isn't already there, which isn't suitable for adding a new node.  Sorry, but you should visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree and consider what algorithm you're implementing; you've got "the wrong thing" here, not "the right thing with a bug".

Comment: I am very familiar with the recursive algorithm but the assignment says "No recursion allowed" since we just moved to imperative from functional (Lisp) this year.

Answer (score 1):

You search

```
    nd = search_bst(*tloc, k);
```

and them immediatly afterwards throw away the search result

```
    nd = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Are you sure that's what you want?
You may as well leave the search out of your code!